# Why does AzureBlobClient.ExistsAsync throw a 404 error?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am creating a `BlobClient` like so

```
private BlobClient CreateBlobClient(string container, string key) =>
    new BlobContainerClient(ConnectionString, container).GetBlobClient(key);
```

Sometimes, when I call `ExistsAsync` on this `BlobClient` instead of returning `false` the client throws a `RequestFailedException` with `e.Status == 404`.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Surely I am not supposed to be wrapping this call with a catch?

```
            var client = CreateBlobClient(container, key);
            try
            {
                // Surprisingly, ExistsAsync throws an exception if the blob is not found.
                Azure.Response<bool> result = await client.ExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                return result.Value;
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException e) when (e.Status == 404)
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Additional info:

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage version 4.0.2

The entry for this code is as follows

1. Blob is uploaded
2. A message is posted to ServiceBus
3. This function runs

I then create a BlobClient to check if a pair of files exist `uploaded.txt` and `uploaded.txt.sig` - it is the `ExistsAsync` check that sometimes throws an exception with error code 404 instead of just returning false.

Comment: have you ever found a solution for this? looks like with the key it doesnt work

Comment: I don't understand "with the key it doesnt work"

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce the code replacing `key` with `blobName` in [GetBlobClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobclient?view=azure-dotnet). And it works.

```
BlobClient client = new BlobContainerClient("connectionString", "containerName").GetBlobClient("blobName");
                
Azure.Response<bool> result = await client.ExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
Console.WriteLine("result: " + result.Value);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying. I know it works, the question is why sometimes it throws a 404 exception on Azure.

Comment: @PeterMorris What's the version of your NuGet package? Is something special when throwing the 404 error, e.g. character "#%&*"? I tried with Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.5.1, and I failed to reproduce the error. It may be a bug.

Comment: It's a .NET Core, Azure Function app. I have added extra info to the question.

Comment: I can't find a method to reproduce the error. If the error doesn't occur regularly, `try-catch` can be used to check if files exist. You could feedback to [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage).